# Why add extra space between a word and punctuation (e.g. a period, question mark, etc.)?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, typography, spacing

I was just wondering this because of noticing a lot of people I've worked with typed this way.

Examples:

Okay, that's great .

Thanks, Stephanie .

Was there anything else ?

I was wondering if there is something that this could derive from.

Comment: Those are all wrong—every single one of them.

Comment: I've yet to be convinced that questions like this are really meaningful. When one writes, spaces are probably normally distributed. The _choice_ of punctuation is a different matter, as different choices have [hopefully] agreed different usages.